# POST request receive large data in plain/text format in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, performance, inputstream

I'm currently receiving POST requests which contain large data in `plain/text` format in spring boot.

We are receiving 5MB of data in each request and it takes approximately 2-3seconds to convert InputStream to String. I wanted to know a faster method to convert InputStream to String for a large dataset.

Sample Code:

```
@PostMapping(value = "receivingRequest", consumes = "plain/text")
public String receivingRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    for (int length; (length = request.getInputStream().read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
        result.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    String requiredData = result.toString();
    ... rest of the code uses requiredData
}
```

Comment: Why not just `@RequestBody String requiredData` instead of `HttpServlerRequest request`? Spring will now read it using proper measures. But do you really need that large of a `String`? What is it you are doing with it? Looks like you are actually retrieving a large file and process it.

Comment: @M.Deinum It is a third-party server that requests our server, it is according to their docs. And `@RequestBody` will take more time to fetch data compared to InputStream

Comment: That's interesting as it does more or less the same. Nonetheless I'm still wonder why would you need a large string, it still feels as if you are reading a file into a large string then processing it line by line, instead of directly processing it line by line (or part by part). That way you wouldn't need to read it in its totally (saves you a whole pass over the body).

Comment: @M.Deinum The string is actually XML data, so after getting the string I'm converting the string to the XML Dto.

Comment: Generally you can do that directly from the inputstream, without the need to first convert to a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

A `BufferedInputStream` should improve the network transfer speed.

```
new BufferedInputStream(request.getInputStream()).read(buffer)
```

Default `BIS` buffer size is 8192. You could experiment with the constructor that takes a custom buffered size to see if that helps further, though I think that probably is as large as needed to handle the underlying TCP block size.